# WPF: DependencyProperty of custom control fails when using several instances of the control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I've built a custom control in WPF that inherits from ListBox. In this I have implementet my own property that is a BindingList. To make this property bindable I've implemeneted it as a DependencyProperty:

```
public BindingList<CheckableListItem> CheckedItems
{
    get
    {
        return (BindingList<CheckableListItem>)GetValue(MultiComboBox.CheckedItemsProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MultiComboBox.CheckedItemsProperty, value);
    }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedItemsProperty;
```

I register this DependencyProperty in a static constructor inside my custom control:

```
CheckedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedItems",
    typeof(BindingList<CheckableListItem>),
    typeof(MultiComboBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new BindingList<CheckableListItem>()));
```

(MultiComboBox is the name of my custom control. CheckableListItem is a simple class I've written just for this purpose).

This BindingList is then updated inside the custom control (never outside) as the user interacts with it.

When I use my custom control in XAML I bind to the CheckItems property with the mode "OneWayToSource". I'm using the MVVM pattern and the property in the ViewModel  that I'm binding to is also a BindingList. The ViewModel never affects this list, it just reacts at the changes that the custom control make to the list. The property in the ViewModel looks like this:

```
private BindingList<CheckableListItem> _selectedItems;
public BindingList<CheckableListItem> SelectedItems
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItems;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedItems)
        {
            if (_selectedItems != null)
            {
                _selectedItems.ListChanged -= SelectedItemsChanged;
            }
            _selectedItems = value;
            if (_selectedItems != null)
            {
                _selectedItems.ListChanged += SelectedItemsChanged;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItems");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm listening to changes made to the list (these changes always occur inside my custom control), and in the "SelectedItemsChanged"-method I update my Model accordingly.

Now...this works great when I have one of these controls in my View. However, if I put two (or more) of them in the same View strange things start to happen. This will of course mean that I'll have two lists with selected items in my ViewModel. But if do something in the View that changes one of the lists, both lists are affected! That is, the event handlers for the event ListChanged is triggered for both list if changes are made to any one of them!

**Does anyone recognize this problem and/or have a solution to it? What is wrong with my implementation?**

My first though is that the DependencyProperty is static. Normally that means shared between all instances. But I guess DependencyProperties work in some other "magical" way so that might not be the problem.

Any tips or hints is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with a collection-type dependency property. My solution was taken from the MSDN article on [Collection-Type Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx). It was adding the following line

```
SetValue(OperatorsPropertyKey, new List<ListBoxItem>()); //replace key and type
```

in the constructor of my control because it seems that a collection-type dependency property constructor is being called only once no matter how many instances your control containing this collection has (static eh).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you bound both/all the Views to the same ViewModel. That would explain that changes to one cause changes in the other.

Comment: All the instances of the custom control are in the same View and thus are bound to the same ViewModel. But they are all bound to separate properties (BindingLists) on the ViewModel, so that should not be a problem.